# QueryStringBinder for List[String]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Using Play 2.0.1 I defined the following route:

```
GET  /demo/list controllers.Demos.listDemos(page: Int ?= 0, orderBy: Int ?= 1, nameFilter: String ?= "", versionFilter: Long ?= -1, tagFilter: List[String] ?= Nil)
```

But I get this error on compile:

```
No QueryString binder found for type List[String]. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.
```

I found the code from Play 2.1-RC (not officially released yet) which would solve the issue:

```
/**
* QueryString binder for List
*/
  implicit def bindableList[T: QueryStringBindable] = new QueryStringBindable[List[T]] {
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = Some(Right(bindList[T](key, params)))
    def unbind(key: String, values: List[T]) = unbindList(key, values)
  }

  /**
* QueryString binder for java.util.List
*/
  implicit def bindableJavaList[T: QueryStringBindable] = new QueryStringBindable[java.util.List[T]] {
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = Some(Right(bindList[T](key, params).asJava))
    def unbind(key: String, values: java.util.List[T]) = unbindList(key, values.asScala)
  }

  private def bindList[T: QueryStringBindable](key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): List[T] = {
    for {
      values <- params.get(key).toList
      rawValue <- values
      bound <- implicitly[QueryStringBindable[T]].bind(key, Map(key -> Seq(rawValue)))
      value <- bound.right.toOption
    } yield value
  }

  private def unbindList[T: QueryStringBindable](key: String, values: Iterable[T]): String = {
    (for (value <- values) yield {
      implicitly[QueryStringBindable[T]].unbind(key, value)
    }).mkString("&")
  }
```

But after a couple of hours trying, Play still doesn't find the code. I've tried using a custom object and implicit conversions to that object,but it still doesn't work.

How can I force Play to do the implicit conversion?

**Update**

I want to avoid 2.1-SNAPSHOT if possible as I'm concerned about its stability, but I will use it if there is no other way. I tried the solution from 4e6 but it did not work:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                 
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: 'compile'. It was required from org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;4.2.0.Final compile
[warn]  :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.2 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My sbt plugin contains this:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy Snapshots", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/",
  "DefaultMavenRepository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
  "JavaNet1Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/1/")

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to move your project to `2.1-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: @4e6 I would like to avoid that if possible, as I have to publish it in Heroku and I don't believe SNAPSHOT is available via SBT. Although if it is, that would work :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it at last. The code used is:

Under **models**, file **QueryBinders.scala**:

```
package models

import play.api.mvc.{JavascriptLitteral, QueryStringBindable}


/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: pvillega
 * Date: 07/05/12
 * Time: 12:06
 * QueryStringBinders for some data types missing in 2.0.1
 */
//TODO: remove when updating to 2.1
object QueryBinders {

  /**
   * QueryString binder for List
   */
  implicit def bindableList[T: QueryStringBindable] = new QueryStringBindable[List[T]] {
    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = Some(Right(bindList[T](key, params)))
    def unbind(key: String, values: List[T]) = unbindList(key, values)
  }

  private def bindList[T: QueryStringBindable](key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): List[T] = {
    for {
      values <- params.get(key).toList
      rawValue <- values
      bound <- implicitly[QueryStringBindable[T]].bind(key, Map(key -> Seq(rawValue)))
      value <- bound.right.toOption
    } yield value
  }

  private def unbindList[T: QueryStringBindable](key: String, values: Iterable[T]): String = {
    (for (value <- values) yield {
      implicitly[QueryStringBindable[T]].unbind(key, value)
    }).mkString("&")
  }

  /**
   * Convert a Scala List[T] to Javascript array
   */
  implicit def litteralOption[T](implicit jsl: JavascriptLitteral[T]) = new JavascriptLitteral[List[T]] {
    def to(value: List[T]) = "[" + value.map { v => jsl.to(v)+"," } +"]"
  }

}
```

On **Build.scala**:

```
 val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here
      lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "style.less"),
      routesImport += "models.QueryBinders"
    )
```

This will have to be removed when updating to 2.1, but it works and it avoids all the issues I had trying to update the project to 2.1 Snapshot.

Comment: The JavaScript part was added later on, so the corrected version can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997782/how-to-pass-a-variable-being-an-array-in-javascript-to-a-controller-accepting-li/12999785#12999785

Answer (score -1):

You can move your project to play `2.1-SNAPSHOT` instead (see ["Create a new application without having Play installed"](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/NewApplication) section of documentation). All you need is to change `sbt-plugin` version and add extra resolvers. Here is my version of `plugins.sbt`

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy Snapshots", url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/",
  "Codahale Repo" at "http://repo.codahale.com")

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

#### Update

I don't know why you have problem with `slf4j` dependency. It is successfully downloaded from typesafe releases for me. You can try to explicitly add this repository to your application config (I mean `Build.scala`, not `plugins.sbt`).

```
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1!slf4j-api.jar (538ms)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it fails with unresolved dependencies on slf4j :(

Comment: I belive, `slf4j` resides at `DefaultMavenRepository`, so you can try to add it. See also [predefined resolvers](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Resolvers).

Comment: I've just cleaned my local ivy cache and made `sbt clean update`. Every dependency was successfully updated with my initial config. Do you have `0.11.2` sbt version?

Comment: did all that, it didn't work in my existing project, still same error. I'll update question.