# Play 2.0 Java: Bind an array from request

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I... stuck o.O

I've params in foreign request:

```
param[62537]=abc;
param[20356]=cde;
param[92837]=fgh;
```

And I'm looking for **any** way for binding them ie. with `DynamicForm`.

I can get param with:

```
DynamicForm dynamicForm = form().bindFromRequest();
String firstParam = dynamicForm.field("param[62537]").value();
```

But of course I *dont know* the indexes as they are selected within the `client-side` form created by the independent app.

When I'm trying to use:

```
String[] firstParam = dynamicForm.field("param").value(); // it's NULL
String[] firstParam = dynamicForm.get("param"); // it's NULL
```

or even

```
String[] params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("param");
     // it's still NULL
```

Did I miss something really basic, or Play just can't do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the prettiest way, but did you try to get the keys of the Map returned by asFormUrlEncoded:

```
Set<String> keys = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
     // check if key begin with "param["
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nico I just started considering that solution, et voilà - you wrote it. I don't care if it's pretty now as the problem was a blocker for me :)

Comment: I'm glad that I finally helped you !

Comment: as of play 2.1.3 I couldn't find a better option. I implemented a variant in the comment.

Comment: This solution works but I just wanted to check if there's a better solution for play 2.3.8 yet?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why this does not work is that there is no QueryStringBinder for List[String] or Array[String] available yet in the framework. As far as I know, this is planned for Play 2.1.

If you need it now, you can try the solution shown here: [QueryStringBinder for List[String]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464268/querystringbinder-for-liststring)

Comment: Thank you for info, I need to check if I can (and how to) use it in Java controller.

Comment: how would you do that in play 2.1 ?