# How to delete list of files using checkbox in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to play framework and i  have a list of files and i wanna add check box so that i can delete the all the checked files  on clicking the delete button, i am displaying the list of files using scala language, help is really needed

```
  @form(action = routes.Application.delete, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {     
@for(order1 <- listfiles) {

    @if(order1.isDirectory()) { }
     else {                
     <input type="checkbox" name="@order1">@order1.getName()
    }
  }
  <input type="submit" name="delete">
  }
```

where @order1.getName() is the name  of the file

Comment: have u tried  filename.delete() ????

Comment: ofcorse, but how to pass the list of selected file name so that i can delete all the selected at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass them as an array of params, take a look at the [nico_ekito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026750/1066240) to find how you can access them in the controller.

Optionally you can use ie. JavaScript to join all filenames/identifiers into one comma-separated `String` and then just split it in controller to `List<String>` which maybe will be even easier.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use special syntax for name attributes [], to let to know play that you will send list of elements:

`@for((value,index) <- listfiles.zipWithIndex ) {
   <input type="checkbox" name="files[index]">@value.getName()</input>
   }`

and then you can bind them to list in you form mapping like this

files -> list(text)