# How to bind a array from checkboxes in a form in Play with Java?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

Got the following form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="x"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="y"> 
...
```

This shall be bound to something I can iterate over. I could do:

```
  ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
  int i = 0;
  while(pageForm.field("tags["+i+"]").value() != null) {
     tags.add(pageForm.field("tags["+i+"]").value());
     i++;
  }
```

But that seems kind of ugly.

Found the following solution, but I can't figure out how to get the values of the keys... #noob

[Play 2.0 Java: Bind an array from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019070/play-2-0-java-bind-an-array-from-request)

Anyone a better approach?

Comment: TBH I have no idea if there's better solution than Nico suggested in the mentioned post, I;m using it still