# Play Framework routes function types

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

I wanted to know if we can pass a Map or List in a function like we pass Int or Long or String etc? If yes then how if we have a Map?

I am using play 2.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in 2.0.4, unless you define some implicit query binders. Play 2.1+ has defined query binder for generic List (i.e. `List[T]`). You can copy implementation from the repository and paste it into your project (as I did - see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997782/how-to-pass-a-variable-being-an-array-in-javascript-to-a-controller-accepting-li)).

Comment: thanks a bunch. will look into it. seems like the answer to my query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'm guessing that you are referring to the Play `/conf/routes` dispatch mechanism, where a route statement like:

```
GET /hello/:id      controllers.Application.hello(id: Int)
```

Will be compiled so that `id` is parsed to an `Int` (or whatever), and passed to the `hello` Action. Guessing even more, you probably want to parse the query string (e.g. `"a=1&b=2"` to `Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> "2"`), and pass it to an Action as a `Map[String, String]` parameter.

I don't think this is possible. You can write a route entry that refers to the query string, and you can use regular expressions, but that won't get you there. To access the query parameters of a GET request, add a `request` parameter to the Action, and look at `request.queryString`